# How can I say "on a second thought" in Italian?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

In English we use "on a second thought" to express that we're thinking again about a previously made choice. I've seen this expression in a comment to this post, [A word whose meaning is "one whose diet includes fish but no other meat"](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/a-word-whose-meaning-is-one-whose-diet-includes-fish-but-no-other-meat), and I wondered how to express that in Italian.

Another example:  we can say, "You know, on a second thought, I think I'll go to watch that film" if we previously decided not to watch it.

How can we say a similar expression in Italian?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd say *a ripensarci* (slightly more formal) or *ora che ci penso*, where something like *di nuovo* (“again”) or *meglio* (“better”) is implied.

Comment: Also "ripensandoci ...", "pensandoci bene/meglio..."

Comment: or *a pensarci bene...*

Comment: Upvoted but altough "ora che ci penso" might be used to express pretty much the same thing we are all understanding, it is not correct in this case, nor it implies "di nuovo" or "meglio", because it states the exact opposite of "a ripensarci", it means that you didn't tought about something previously but you're doing it right now

Comment: Also, referring to @martina 's comment, being even pickier, "a pensarci bene" it's not correct either, because it doesn't imply having tought of such thing previously, while as with "ora che ci penso" I agree that it might be used to express pretty much the same thing

Comment: @kos, I partially agree with you, but I believe that while the literal meaning of *ora che ci penso* would entail that one didn't previously think about the subject at all, its actual meaning is that you evaluated it superficially or fleetingly, while now are actually considering it fully. So I'd confirm it as a candidate to convey the meaning of “on a second thought”.

Comment: @DaG Probably I've been pointlessly picky here, because it *seems* clear from the question that the original poster's scope it's not a literal translation. If he wants an expression semantically equivalent (which is likely at this point), than "ora che ci penso" is totally fine, altough if for some reason he needs a perfect literal equivalent, I don't think that "ora che ci penso" would fit well

Answer (score 8):

*Ora che ci penso* - in case when you just want to add some more details or clarify something.

> "Pensi a questo: il vestitino, per caso, non era perfettamente asciutto?" "Oddio!" sclamò il dottore. "Ora che ci penso... sì, era asciutto."

*Anzi* - in case when you change your mind, so that your second thought is completely different from the first one.

> "Anche nei laboratori e nella serra è tutto okay, ma in ogni caso non è che lui li frequentasse molto. Anzi, non ricordo per niente l'ultima volta che è stato qui."

Comment: "Ora che ci penso" is "now that I think about it". It's not exactly the same, although it's good enough 90% of the time (that is - when your rethinking is instantaneous).

Comment: I agree with Tobia Tesan, see [this](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5355/how-can-i-say-on-a-second-thought-in-italian#comment7793_5356) comment

Answer (score 8):

*Ripensandoci* has the exact meaning you're looking for.